# Google Calendar API: How to stop channel subscription with revoked credentials

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

The problem I have is that I want to stop an ongoing channel subscription in the case of a user revoking his credentials in my app.
When a user is revoking his credentials, I cannot authenticate the api call to stop his channel subscription anymore

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/channels/stop

I tried to call the function anyway which resulted in an "invalid credentials" error from the Google API